# How to run system command from npm package.json?

Tags: npm, package.json

I'd like to run system command from package.json, like:

```
"scripts": {
  "adb setup": "adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081",
}
```

But get just `npm ERR! missing script: adb`.

Can't find any docs about it.

Comment: are you able to run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` in your terminal as normal? And are you running `npm run adb setup` when you see that error? Or what are you running?

Comment: I can do `adb reverse ...` ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: make script name without spaces:
`"adb-setup": "..."` works just perfectly.